# Negative supply from LM3940

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, ldo

I got a bunch of LM3940 to convert 5V to 3.3V. I wanted to use the same to make -3.3 V so I switched the ground and output. In the schematic the top circuit works fine and I get 3.3V out. I expect V_out in the second circuit to be -3.3V but I am getting +3.3V. Can someone help? Is this something to do with the LM3940?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fASS1y.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Why not use op-amp inverter? or a circuit that is design to invert ?

Comment: If you look at the internal circuit of the lm3940 in the datasheet, you see that the device isn't made to output on his gnd pin

Comment: @MathieuL How would you make an opamp output negative voltage without supplying one first?

Comment: It will not work.  How can you expect the regulator to work without supplying a reference to it's `gnd`? Use a switching regulator capable of providing a negative output.

Comment: @EugeneSh I was basing it off of another regulator design I saw [here](http://www.cui.com/product/resource/v78-500.pdf). I thought since the potential difference across the OUT and GND is 3.3V, I should get -3.3V if I inverted it.

Comment: Why would there be *any* potential difference? who is forcing it? BTW, the linked part is the switching regulator I am talking about.

Answer (score 2):

As the comments suggest, you can't produce a negative voltage from a simple linear regulator like that, unless you supply them with a negative voltage to begin with.

A simple and cheap IC solution is the [MAX1720](http://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/charge-pumps/MAX1720.html) and family.  They just require two capacitors to make a fairly regulated output voltage opposite polarity of their input voltage.

[image: max1720 typical application]

In general, you need a switch of some sort to produce a negative voltage (through either a switched capacitive solution like above, or a switching regulator like the V78-500 series).  Both the MAX1720 and the V78-500 series regulators have internal switches.  The LM3940 do not, as they are linear regulators.